# How to get data from observable?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Im trying to get some data from a request. I have an observable function that gives me the data inside of `.subscribe`, but whenever i try to get that data outside ( in a variable defined in the class) it will return me `undefined` and its quite annoying

Component.ts:

```
import { ProjectService } from '../services/project.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-loader',
  templateUrl: './project-loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-loader.component.css']
})
export class ProjectLoaderComponent implements OnInit {
  projects:any;
  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getProjects(); 
   }
   getProjects(){
     this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe(data=>{
       this.projects= data;

     })

   }
 }
```

Component.html:

```
{{projects[0].id}}
```

The html is just for testing porpouses right now, so it has only 1 line. FYI the data returned in the observable function is an json array.

Array Example:

```
    {
        "id": "REDACTED",
        "projectName": "REDACTED",
        "projectId": "REDACTED"
    },
    {
        "id": "REDACTED",
        "projectName": "REDACTED",
        "projectId": "REDACTED"
    }
]
```

(Redacted are strings from a private db :P)

Comment: Is it possible to share the ProjectService code?

Comment: @AkshayaJeevan i solved it, i just had to do a `*ngFor` on the html and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. I just had to use a `*ngFor` to encapsulate the projects like this:

```
<div *ngFor=" let project of projects">
<button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" (click)="openProject(project.id)" >{{project.projectName}}</button>
</div>
```